# Using UmbracoIntegrationTest causes Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'config') after upgrade to Umbraco 10

Tags: umbraco

I upgraded my Umbraco project from 9 to 10 and now my integration tests don't run.

I created a new Umbraco 10 project to do a test and see if I missed some upgrade steps, but the issue also occurs in the brand new project.

I created the following simple test to reproduce the problem:

```
  [TestFixture]
  [UmbracoTest(Database = UmbracoTestOptions.Database.NewEmptyPerTest)]
  public class TestClass : UmbracoIntegrationTest {

    [Test]
    public void Test1() {
      Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
    }
  }
```

The test fails to run with the following output:

```
  Test1
   Source: TestClass.cs line 21
   Duration: 17 ms

  Message: 
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'config')
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

  Stack Trace: 
ChainedBuilderExtensions.AddConfiguration(IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, IConfiguration config, Boolean shouldDisposeConfiguration)
ChainedBuilderExtensions.AddConfiguration(IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, IConfiguration config)
UmbracoIntegrationTest.<CreateHostBuilder>b__5_0(HostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder)
HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
HostBuilder.Build()
UmbracoHostBuilderDecorator.Build()
UmbracoIntegrationTest.Setup()
--TearDown
UmbracoIntegrationTest.TearDownAsync()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added appsettings.Tests.json in you integration test project with test database configs as follows:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Umbraco.Cms.Tests": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
      "DisableColors": true
    }
  },
  "Tests": {
    "Database": {
      "DatabaseType": "SQLite",
      "PrepareThreadCount": 4,
      "SchemaDatabaseCount": 4,
      "EmptyDatabasesCount": 2,
      "SQLServerMasterConnectionString": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I have added
CustomUmbracoIntegrationTest.cs (from: https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/v10/contrib/tests/Umbraco.Tests.Integration/Testing/UmbracoIntegrationTest.cs)
&
CustomGlobalSetupTeardown.cs (from: https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/v10/contrib/tests/Umbraco.Tests.Integration/GlobalSetupTeardown.cs)
in my project instead of these files from the package.

My integration test classes inherit from CustomUmbracoIntegrationTest instead of Umbraco.Cms.Tests.Integration.Testing.UmbracoIntegrationTest

the tests will work after this change.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I implemented your suggestions, but now I get a different error.

It's complaining in UmbracoIntegrationTestBase.ConfigureTestDatabaseFactory on line 137 at the Assert.IsFalse(factory.Configured) line. Seems it wants the factory not to be configured. I'm new to Umbraco, so I don't know what this error is about.

Comment: Message: 
  Expected: False
  But was:  True

UmbracoIntegrationTestBase.ConfigureTestDatabaseFactory(TestDbMeta meta, IUmbracoDatabaseFactory factory, IRuntimeState state, IOptionsMonitor`1 connectionStrings)
UmbracoIntegrationTestBase.SetupTestDatabase(TestUmbracoDatabaseFactoryProvider testUmbracoDatabaseFactoryProvider, IOptionsMonitor`1 connectionStrings, IUmbracoDatabaseFactory databaseFactory, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IRuntimeState runtimeState)
UmbracoIntegrationTestBase.UseTestDatabase(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
CustomUmbracoIntegrationTest.Setup() line 77